# Копирование или ссылка?

Tags: php, оптимизация, ссылки, передача-данных

Возможно я задам самый глупый вопрос, но хотелось бы получить однозначный ответ:

В один из методов класса я передаю массив со значениями. До "отправки" массива в метод и после массив больше никак не используется. Внутри метода данные используются сугубо для вывода, то есть данные не изменяются. Как лучше поступить:

Так:

```
$data['key'] = $some_data;
$this->someMethod($data);
```

Или так:

```
$data['key'] = &$some_data;
$this->someMethod($data);
```

То есть как лучше передать данные: скопировав их, или просто дать ссылку?

P.S. Мне почему-то кажется, что передать ссылку менее ресурсозатратно, потому что иногда приходится передавать большие объемы данных. Но в исходном коде PHP я не рылся, поэтому не знаю всех этих тонкостей его работы.

Comment: а в data что-нибудь еще есть?

Comment: Насколько я знаю особой разницы нет. Если внутри метода массив в самом деле не изменяюется, то оптимизатор PHP автом-ки преобразует его (внутренне) в ссылку.

Comment: @hindmost, пожалуйста, оформите ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @hindmost, про это можно где-то прочитать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Вам не нужно беспокоиться о таких вещах. Движок PHP автоматически распознает их и оптимизирует. В вашем случае вместо локальной копии массива внутренне будет использована ссылка на него.

Вообще на SO уже отвечали на подобные вопросы. Вот наиболее популярные: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479073/when-is-it-good-to-use-pass-by-reference-in-php), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157799/when-to-pass-by-reference-in-php).
Ниже вольный перевод первого из них (имхо во втором больше эмоций, чем объяснений).

Передача массива по ссылке имеет смысл, только если вы планируете изменять его внутри функции. При этом массив должен быть очень большим, чтобы выигрыш в производительности и использовании памяти стал ощутимым. В противном случае лучше вместо этого использовать функциональный подход: изменять локальную копию массива и возвращать ее (из функции). Несмотря на доп. расходы по хранению копии массива, это делает код понятнее и к тому же позволяет избежать нежелательных побочных эффектов, возникающих при использовании ссылок.

Если вас интересуют детали, есть также [статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/43489/).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не собираетесь модифицировать данные, то передавайте переменную без указателя.
Ускорение работы не заметит никто, но листинг кода может поставить в заблуждение.